# Different taxonomy.php for different custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, template-hierarchy

I have `taxonomy.php` template file for post_type "posts" but I'd like to use another taxonomy.php but just use/apply it to a custom post type. Is this somehow possible to make another taxonomy.php file just for a specific custom post type?

Comment: With the same tax archive url how users will access two different archives ?

Comment: not necessarily with the same url but the principle of using a single taxonomy.php "type of" file

Comment: what is the taxonomy and terms name of custom post type?

Comment: Can't you just perform a check to see what the post type is and then look for a template part with the same name and if the template part doesn't exist use a default?

Comment: @yobddigi I suppose... do you have an example of how to conditionally check for the post type?

Comment: @Pete I posted it [as an answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/228838/76059)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if the taxonomy T of post type A is logically different enough from taxonomy T of post type B to make you need different urls and display and whatever more, then it is probably much better to have two different taxonomies for the different post types.

The point of having the same tag for different content is to show they are related and you say that you don't actually want them to be related

Comment: I get your point, but... I want to use this as a means to utilize the hierarchy structure and therefore I only need one template file (taxonomy.php) to apply to all the different custom taxonomies I have for that particular CPT.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do and maybe you should edit the question and give a more concrete example, but in general I would say that ignoring the logical and structural foundations in order to have a quick hack will most likely come to hunt you in the future, usually at a bad time when you will not be able to just change your design.

Answer (score 0):

## [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) & [get_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/)

We can do this by combining `get_template_part()` and `get_post_type()` like this:

```
get_template_part( 'taxonomy', get_post_type() );
```

How this works is `get_post_type()` will return the name of the post type that is currently shown and passes that to `get_template_part()`, so if we’re on a Post, it’ll attempt to load `taxonomy-post.php` and fallback to `taxonomy.php` if `taxonomy-post.php` doesn't exist. If we’re on a Page, `taxonomy-page.php` and `taxonomy.php`. If we’re working with custom post types, say a Book, it will look for `taxonomy-book.php` and fall back to `taxonomy.php`.

### WP Developer Doc's

[get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

[get_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/)

#### Some more good reading

[Understanding get_template_part by Konstantin Kovshenin](https://kovshenin.com/2013/get_template_part/)